# If MySQL Result Empty display a confirm box

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I'm using some crazy mixture of PHP/JavaScript/HTML/MySQL

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE submitted = 0;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row != NULL) {  
   // Display a confirm box saying "Not everyone has entered a bid, continue?"
}
// If confirmed yes run more queries
// Else nothing
```

What is the best way to have this confirm box display, before completing the rest of the queries?

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Question added.

Comment: Consider doing a `SELECT COUNT(*)` rather than a `SELECT *` if all you need is to check whether certain records exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if($row != NULL) {  
    ?>
    <script>alert("not everyone has submitted their bid.");</script>
    <?php
    }
```

or

```
    <?php
    function jsalert($alert_message){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$alert_message."');</script>";
    }

    if($row!=null){
        jsalert("Not everyone has submitted their bid.");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: could this be tidied up a little bit, if indeed thats what the question was after ? maybe using a php function so you don't need to break the ?> <?php

Comment: Thanks for the post, however this is not what I am looking for.  I need to user to be able to select whether or not to continue.  If they select yes, then execute more PHP, if they select no, then to probably just echo something.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in 1 continuous block, as *all* of the PHP will execute before the `confirm` (due to server vs. client).

You will need to break these into 2 separate steps and have the client mediate between them:

`part1.php`:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE submitted = 0;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row != NULL) { ?>

<form id="confirmed" action="part2.php" method="post">
    <noscript>
        <label>Not everyone has entered a bid, continue?</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Yes">
    </noscript>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (confirm("Not everyone has entered a bid, continue?")) {
        document.getElementById('confirmed').submit();
    }
</script>

<?
} else {
    include_once('part2.php');
}
?>
```

`part2.php`:

```
<?php
    // assume confirmed. execute other queries.
?>
```

Comment: I think this one will work best, might have to make a couple changes so I don't reconnect to the database and such again.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE submitted = 0;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row != NULL) {  
   // more queries here
} else {
   echo "<script>alert('Empty result');</script>";
}
```

Comment: I think $row != NULL would imply the opposite of an empty result ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing it out. Updated answer.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella Thanks for helping me by answering my question. I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Play with this code and you will get it to work eventually. I know you are not looking for just alertbox , instead you are looking for something like "yes or no" informational box. So check this out.

```
<?php
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayBOX(){
    var name=confirm("Not everyone has entered a bid, continue?")
    if (name==true){
        //document.write("Do your process here..")
        window.location="processContinuing.php";

    }else{
        //document.write("Stop all process...")
        window.location="stoppingProcesses.php";
    }
}
</script>
</head>


<?php
$query = "SELECT * faculty SET submitted = 0;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row != NULL) {  
echo "<script>displayBox();</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I can use PHP in document.write?  I thought since javascript is client and PHP is server it wouldn't work

Comment: No you cannot. But you can pass control using redirect. I have modified the above example. Have a look.